# Getting form digest without using SOAP

Tags: rest, soap, request-digest

Is there a way to get the Form Digest value without using a SOAP call?

Because accessing CSOM SharePoint web services require  digest value, and because the form digest request requires SOAP, we are forced to give SOAP and REST web service access to our user instead of just REST access.

Is there some way to get form digest without using SOAP?

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/114387/8992).

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you adding your solution to SP page? If yes, you can get the form digest value from the page without any API call.

Comment: Confirmed @DylanCristy was correct. Closing.

Comment: I made the request but I cannot seem to use the digest value. `[[\r{\r\"SchemaVersion\":\"15.0.0.0\",\"LibraryVersion\":\"15.0.5357.1000\",\"ErrorInfo\":{\r\"ErrorMessage\":\"The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.\",\"ErrorValue\":null,\"TraceCorrelationId\":\"4a3e0da0-00f4-c012-5d16-3844abf4f22e\",\"ErrorCode\":-2130575251,\"ErrorTypeName\":\"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException\"\r},\"TraceCorrelationId\":\"4a3e0da0-00f4-c012-5d16-3844abf4f22e\"\r}\r]]`

Comment: Ah I was missing other required headers that the other ticket had omitted.